# How to configure a custom SiteMapNode for a sitemap?

Tags: sitemap, sitemapnode

I created a class which inherits from SiteMapNode and overrode the Title property of it. However how and where do I configure it so that my sitemap (and custom sitemapprovider) takes this custom SiteMapNode implementation instead of the default one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparantly this should be done by creating a custom sitemapprovider which inherits from StaticSiteMapProvider instead of XmlSiteMapProvider.